# Call Child Event from Parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Before the parent component allows the tab to be switched, I would like the child tab to validate itself.

I'm thinking to pass the onActive Event from the parent to its children, `<ClientInfo/> and <Details/>`.

This would allow the children to validate themselves and perform any actions they need to do before the tab gets switched.

I'm not sure how the syntax would look. I believe I need to bind the event to pass to the child. Does the concept make sense? My code sure doesn't. How could we get this going?

```
  class ParentC extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          value: '0',
        }; 
        this.handleActive = this.handleActive.bind(this);
      }
      render(){
        return(
         <Tabs>
         <Tab label={<h6>Client Info</h6>} value="0" onActive={this.handleActive}>
          <ClientInfo tabChange={this.handleActive}/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab label={<h6>Details</h6>} value="1" onActive={}>
          <Details tabChange={this.handleActive} />
        </Tab>
        </Tabs>
        )
      }
    }
```

tldr; tab event needs to be passed to child component

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you need to *call a child handler from the parent*, you should know that your mindset is a little bit wrong. In React, parents should not **generally** need to invoke anything from their children props.

If you are building a tabs system, I would go with mounting/unmounting the `Tab`s on switch and make use of `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle methods.

However, after reading your question once more, I don't think you need such callbacks however. Here what I propose:

```
class Tab extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // do stuff here
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabTitle">{this.props.title}</div>
    );
  }
}

class TabbedView extends Component {
  state = {
    activeTab: 0,
  };

  onActiveTabChange(idx) {
    this.setState({activeTab: idx});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabs">
        <div className="tabButtons">
          {React.Children.map((c, idx) => (
            <button onClick={this.onActiveTabChange(idx)}>
              {c.props.title}
            </button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="activeTab">
          {React.Children.map(children, (child, idx) => {
            if (idx === this.state.activeTab) {
              return child;
            }
            return null;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Note** my example is not very detailed. I just wanted to give you an idea as the implementation depends on your exact needs.

This is the way I usually structure components like this.

Comment: Thanks for the idea in the future. But Tab is a material-ui component. Sorry I didn't make that clear. I rather just listen to the event that fires from the component